# Meteor cannot add "materialize CSS"

Tags: css, meteor, materialize

I'm getting the following error if I try to add a new package called 'materialize:materialize'

this is my packages in meteor (same as meteor add %packagename%)

```
meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.14                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
jquery@1.11.10                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker@1.1.1                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.2   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@1.2.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.6.1              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.2.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

accounts-ui
accounts-password
materialize:materialize
```

Error I'm receiving, that is stopping me from running the nodeJs server.

```
C:\Projects\ConeTrips>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Projects\ConeTrips ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While loading package materialize:materialize@0.98.0:
   error: Command failed:
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_6\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd
   rebuild --update-binary
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download:
   https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.15/fse-v1.0.15-node-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.15 and node@4.7.3 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back
   to source compile with node-gyp)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py",
   line 16, in <module>
   sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py",
   line 545, in script_main
   return main(sys.argv[1:])
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py",
   line 538, in main
   return gyp_main(args)
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py",
   line 523, in gyp_main
   generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py",
   line 2003, in GenerateOutput
   sln_projects, project_objects, flat=msvs_version.FlatSolution())
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py",
   line 1762, in _GatherSolutionFolders
   return _DictsToFolders('', root, flat)
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py",
   line 1715, in _DictsToFolders
   for folder, contents in bucket.iteritems():
   AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
   gyp ERR! configure error
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
   (C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
   gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
   "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
   "--module=C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-llyqvy\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32\\fse.node"
   "--module_name=fse"
   "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-llyqvy\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32"
   gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.7.3
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
   'C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_6\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
   configure --fallback-to-build
   --module=C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32\fse.node
   --module_name=fse
   --module_path=C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32'
   (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-llyqvy\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp"
   "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.7.3
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
   npm ERR! argv
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
   "rebuild" "--update-binary"
   npm ERR! node v4.7.3
   npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.15 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.15 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\npm-debug.log
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download:
   https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.15/fse-v1.0.15-node-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.15 and node@4.7.3 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back
   to source compile with node-gyp)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py",
   line 16, in <module>
   sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py",
   line 545, in script_main
   return main(sys.argv[1:])
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py",
   line 538, in main
   return gyp_main(args)
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py",
   line 523, in gyp_main
   generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py",
   line 2003, in GenerateOutput
   sln_projects, project_objects, flat=msvs_version.FlatSolution())
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py",
   line 1762, in _GatherSolutionFolders
   return _DictsToFolders('', root, flat)
   File
   "C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py",
   line 1715, in _DictsToFolders
   for folder, contents in bucket.iteritems():
   AttributeError: 'MSVSProject' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
   gyp ERR! configure error
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
   (C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
   gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
   "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
   "--module=C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-llyqvy\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32\\fse.node"
   "--module_name=fse"
   "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-llyqvy\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32"
   gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.7.3
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
   'C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_6\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
   configure --fallback-to-build
   --module=C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32\fse.node
   --module_name=fse
   --module_path=C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v46-win32-ia32'
   (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\materialize_materialize\\0.98.0\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-llyqvy\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp"
   "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\node_modules\fsevents
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.7.3
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
   npm ERR! argv
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\Aleksei\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2_6\\mt-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
   "rebuild" "--update-binary"
   npm ERR! node v4.7.3
   npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.15 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.15 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!
   C:\Users\Aleksei\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\materialize_materialize\0.98.0\npm\node_modules\.temp-llyqvy\npm-debug.log


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: May I suggest you to use NPM instead of an Atmosphere package for materialize. The atmosphere package is just a wrapper. The documentation https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#client-npm will help you to do so if you wish. Sorry, my comment doesn't respond to your question directly.

Comment: I will try that later, thanks mate! For now Using bootstrap v3 & Meteor instead.

Comment: You are welcome! You can use NPM package also for Bootstrap. That's let you to work in total freedom: using less source file, import component js that you need only in a template, etc.